# How to join to a JOINED subclass in a Hibernate / JPA 2.0 CriteriaQuery?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, inheritance, hibernate-criteria

I need to join from a superclass attribute to its subclass entity (using [JOINED](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/InheritanceType.html#JOINED) inheritance). Tried something like this:

```
root.join(RootClass_.superClassAttribute).as(SubClass.class)
```

...and need to continue this by joining from the subclass to other entities.
But the `as` is returning a `CastFunction` so not sure how this is possible?

(Note: Am using JPA 2.0, not 2.1 so can't use [`treat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#treat-javax.persistence.criteria.Join-java.lang.Class-).)

Comment: The only answer for doing that in Criteria is to use JPA 2.1 TREAT. There are no extra magic methods on there ... the API defines it all and leaves to space for vendor extensions

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a suggestion for how to achieve this outside the Criteria API? I'm aware that I could use native SQL queries as a last resort... but is there a halfway house?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I got it working by constructing the query the other way round - so instead of attempting to join to a subclass it was simply using the parent metamodel class:

```
inverseRoot.join(InverseRootClass_.subClassAttribute).join(ParentClass.attribute)...
```

This worked for my use case but expect there may still be situations where the question needs a better answer - e.g. where the required set of joins includes both children and parents.